# Cannot pass the fetch method information to the instance data

Tags: vue.js, nativescript

When I run the below code, the values inside the `currencie` variable are not displayed.

I cannot pass the fetch method information to the instance data. I would like to fetch the data and display it on the screen. If I use `console.log` I can see the data as expected.

```
 <template>
        <Page class="page">
            <ActionBar title="Tela N°1" class="action-bar" />
            <ScrollView>
                <StackLayout class="home-panel">
                    <!--Add your page content here-->
                    <Label textWrap="true" text="Primeira tela criada usando NativeScript"
                        class="h2 description-label" />
                    <Button text="Segunda Tela" @tap="onButtonTap" />
                    <Button text="Terceira Tela" @tap="onButton" />
                    <ListView class="list-group" for="currencie in currenciess"
                        style="height:1250px">
                        <v-template>
                            <FlexboxLayout flexDirection="row" class="list-group-item">
                                <Label :text="currencie.name" class="list-group-item-heading" style="width: 60%" />
                                <Label :text="currencie.buy" class="list-group-item-heading"
                                    style="width: 60%" />
                            </FlexboxLayout>
                        </v-template>
                    </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </Page>
    </template>

    <script>
        import Second from "./Second";
        import Third from "./Third";
        const http = require("tns-core-modules/http");
        const url = "https://api.hgbrasil.com/finance?key=c5239f9c";
        export default {
            data() {
                return {
                    currenciess: []
                };
            },                    
    mounted() {
                fetch(url)
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(results => {
                        this.currenciess = results.results.currencies.USD;
                    });
            },
        };
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your mounted method. `currenciess` is an array while your `results.results.currencies["USD"]` is an object coming from API. I have created a playground for you [here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=CJFkR2&v=2).

```
mounted() {
            console.log("mounted");
            fetch(url)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(results => {
                    this.currenciess.push(results.results.currencies["USD"]);
                });
        }
```